# R Tidyverse Determine which column value not the same, return two values

Tags: r, tidyverse

Lets say I have this data:

```
df<-data.frame("Row_id"=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8),"A"=c(1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1),"B"=c(0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1),"C"=c(1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1),"D"=c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1),"E"=c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1),"F"=c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1))
```

And as you can see, in most of the rows, the values are all the same.  But lets say I want to create a new variable (or two really) that tells me:

- Is everything in that row the same for variables A through F
- Which one(s) were a "1" if not the same

So for instance in that data above, I'd get new columns that looked like this:
[image]

Marked as tidyverse because I guess I'd prefer that, but flexible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `rowSums` on the columns except the first column to create a logical vector by comparing with the second column.  If the row wise sum is 'n1', then convert it to numeric index by adding 1 and use that to change the values to 'No', 'Yes'.  Then, we create the 'Different' column by looping over the rows, `paste` the `names` of the elements that are not 0 (Here, we could also make use of `ifelse` based on the 'Same' column

```
n1 <- ncol(df[-1])
df$Same <- c("No", "Yes")[(rowSums(df[-1]  == df[,2]) == n1) + 1]
df$Different <-  apply(df[2:7], 1, function(x)
        if(!all(x == 1)) toString(names(x)[x !=0 ]) else "")
```

Comment: Thank you!  This works perfectly!  Follow up question:  Lets say it says "unchecked" instead of "0" and "checked" instead of "1".  Is that easy enough to do the same thing?  If not I can easily make that change first.  Thank you again

Comment: @JoeCrozier if you want to make the reverse, change the `!=0` to `!=1` and `!all(x == 0)`

Comment: @JoeCrozier If your question is to change the 'No', 'Yes' to 'unchecked', checked.  just replace the `c("No", "Yes")` to `c("unchecked", "checked")`

Comment: Ah, thank you.  I think what I was saying would be like this: df$Different <-  apply(df[2:7], 1, function(x)
+     if(!all(x == "Checked")) toString(names(x)[x !="Unchecked"]) else "").  The original program it spits the raw data out of types in those words

Comment: @JoeCrozier ok, got it.  I think that should work, right?  I haven't tested it.  There is still a chance that you may have to check for the leading/lagging spaces

Comment: It worked, I just checked it.  Thank you again!  Now I just have to tackle the different task of pulling the columns I want to compare out of 400 total columns, and then somehow taking these columns you helped me make and put them back in.  Problem for a different day.  Thank you